# What is the proper use case for html <i> element?

Tags: html, icons, italic

At first this question seem simple, from all the real life examples I have seen,  is used for displaying icons. For example the [twitter bootstrap icons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons).

However, when I search  tag in google, the w3c school says  [is for italic text](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp).

I am confused, if  is used for italic text, why is everyone using it for icons? What is the proper use of this tag??

Comment: What about [going to the source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/i.html#i)?

Comment: Thank everyone for answering, as you notified I realize that there is already another question for this and it has been answered. So I'll just go ahead and read that. The result I am looking for is really a good way to represent icons, since a lot of big names are using the <i> tag out side of the spec it creates confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be used to make text styled italic. Most semantic uses for italic text are `<em>`, as it is supported by screen-readers for emphasis.

`<i>` and `<b>` are slowly going out of fashion in favour of using CSS to style text, and preserving `<em>` and `<strong>` for accessibility reasons.

I guess that it was selected for icons since it is the closest element and makes alphabetic sense (i.e. i = icon).

Comment: During recent studies I also learn that using <i> for icons is a bad idea. HTML should contain less non-semantic contents and icons being part of it. Should use css pseudo elements to display icons whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
<i>  was the old way to make text italic in HTML.
```

The tag has now been redefined in HTML5 and I believe TwitterBootstrap just used this convention for icons but it is definitely not a standard way to do icons.

http://w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags

Comment: Which specification deprecated the i element?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags - while it doesn't explicity state deprecated I believe the tags should not be used for italic, especially since the HTML 5 specification has redefined the meaning of <i>

Answer (score 2):

Because HTML has become perverted over the ages.

Official "proper use" in HTML 4.01 is for italic text.

Answer (score 1):

The `<i>` tag is [discouraged](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_some_presentational_elements_like_.3Cb.3E.2C_.3Ci.3E_and_.3Csmall.3E_still_included.3F), because it provides no semantic indication about *why* the text is italic.

To display italic text, the `<em>` tag should be used.  (or a different tag with appropriate semantic meaning, combined with CSS)

More recently, people have started using `<i>` tags for icons, because `i` stands for *icon*.